# Decimal precision of zero when serializing doubles to JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Consider the following JSON object:

```
{
    "value": 0   
}
```

---

Now suppose I'm mapping this to a .NET type `Foo`:

```
class Foo
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

The type of `Foo.Value` is `double`, because `Value` isn't always an integer value.

Using JSON.NET, this works beautifully:

```
Foo deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
```

---

However, observe what happens when I try to convert the object back to its JSON representation:

```
string serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deserialized, Formatting.Indented);
```

Output:

```
{
  "Value": 0.0
}
```

---

Notice the trailing zero? How do I get rid of it?

**EDIT**

I suspect that the answer will be *write your own converter*. If it is, then that's fine and I guess I'll accept that as the answer. I'm just wondering if perhaps there exists an attribute that I don't know of that lets you specify the output format (or similar).

Comment: why to get rid of it?

Comment: That kind of numeric literal notation (`DIGITS.DIGITS`) usually indicates the double type for C-like programming languages. Based on that notation a JSON parser would instantly deserialize that value using the correct data type, avoiding an additional cast / conversion step when setting the value in your C# object.

Comment: @elyashiv because I'm trying to stick to the original specification as closely as possible. But regardless, the _why_ shouldn't really matter. I'm sure there are real use cases for this.

Comment: @NobuGames That's true, but it's also irrelevant for what I'm doing. My code already receives a poorly designed JSON object. All I want to do is reproduce this poor design when I forward the object to someone else. You know, for consistency.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question.Just want to comment on the WHY as I have same issue serializing objects for use on html pages....  Presenting the data directly to enduser like "2.0 liters of milk"  is not wrong, but just over technical, whereas "2.5 liters" makes sense. However I opt to handle it afterwards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that this is a hard-coded behavior of the library:

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L300

If you want to alter the behavior you'll need to edit the library and recompile from source (or choose another JSON library)

Comment: Nice find! That answers it for me. I'll just write a custom converter for this.